# SAS+files compatibilty between Linux and Windows

Tags: sas

Is it possible to make the files (.csv or .xls or .txt) created in Linux to    windows compatibility mode. Here all the files are routed to result_path location and they should be in windows compatibility mode.

I am using the following SAS code to create files in Linux.

```
    %let result_pth = abc/test_folder/test_nas_loc; 

    filename  outref "&result_pth./&sysuserid..linux_file.txt";                                                                                       
    PROC PRINTTO PRINT =outref    new;run;                                                                                                
    data new;
    set sashelp.class;
    run;
    proc print noobs;run; 
    proc printto;                                                               
    run;
```

Comment: By windows compatibility mode, do you mean with `cr+lf` line terminators?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responce Joe, i need the file to be in windows compatibility mode with out CRLF. if we use TERMSTR=CRLF, it will make the file to Linux comapatibility mode. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I don't have any idea what `windows compatibility mode` means if it doesn't mean using the `cr+lf` line terminator.  A regular text file needs `cr+lf` to be a proper text file in Windows.  Other files (xls, xlsx, etc.) are binary files and shouldn't care what OS you're on.  Explain yourself further if `windows compatibility` means something else.

Comment: If you want to open the file in a text editor, and see each record on a separate line, then just use pretty much ANY editor EXCEPT notepad!  For instance Wordpad, Notepad++, Multi-Edit (or anything similar, am not advocating these)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're referring to making a file with the correct line termination character(s), you can do this with the `TERMSTR` option on the file statement.  This only works when using `put` in the data step to write to a file.

```
data _null_;
 set have;
 file "myfile.txt" termstr=crlf dlm=',';
 put _all_;
run;
```

`XLS` or `XLSX` files should be binary files and shouldn't require line terminators.